# Can't access some websites

Tags: networking, ubuntu, dns

I have a networking/dns problem in my laptop. I can't access some websites. For example www.accuweather.com

I am using a wireless connection. The issue is just in my laptop. I can access the sites from my phone.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. I don't know what info should i share. So i can edit my question as you ask for info.

Edit: Even javascript files in superuser.com is not working! Developer console says "Uncaught ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined". So i can't even leave a comment.

I tried OpenDNS, Google DNS, ComodoDNS. Problem persists.

Comment: Change your DNS to OpenDNS and test it.

Comment: If you open a terminal are you able to ping the sites, and have you tried an alternate browser ?    Also, if you run MTR for a while, what does it show with respect of packet loss - it could be your Wireless connection is intermittent.